# Issues with a SQL Server instance alias

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, windows-server

I have the most simple of questions:

I've got a Microsoft SQL Server with two instances, default and a named instance called `Instance1`.

The default instance is running on static TCP/IP port 1433 and the named instance is running on static TCP/IP port 5555.

I'm trying to create an alias to `Instance1` and went to SQL Server Configuration Manager and under SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 Bit) I created an alias as follows:

- `Aliasname: TEST1`
- `Portnumber: 5555`
- `Server: <ServerName>\Instance1`

Then, directly on the SQL Server box I tried the following from a cmd:

- `sqlcmd -S TEST1` ... and I'm connected

Then I did:

```
1> select name from sys.sysdatabases
2> go
```

and I get the DBs that exist on the default instance, rather than `Instance1`.

I've tried changing the alias port to a random port, anything at all, and it will always connect to the default instance, I don't get it.

There are no `MSSQLSvc/` SPNs at all registered for this server, but I can't imagine that having something to do with it.

Basically, no idea what's going on here.

This is a Windows Server 2016 and SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Please update your question with the picture of your Configuration Manager opened   under Server Network Configuration for your DEFAULT instance where we can clearly see port number indicated under IPAll

Comment: P.S. You should not include Instance name under SERVER when create the alias, it should look like this: Server: <ServerName>, Instance name is just ignored as there is port number set.

Comment: Alternatively, you can update your question with the initial part of DEFAULT instance error log where it says on what ports it's listening

Comment: Have you tried identifying the instance by methods that explicitly tell you the name rather than relying on the database set shown? For instance, by running either `SELECT @@SERVERNAME;` or `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName');`? Just to make sure there's no mistake.